# write error: Broken pipe

Tags: python, linux, unix, scripting

I have to run a tool on around 300 directories. Each run take around 1 minute to 30 minute or even more than that. So, I wrote a python script having a loop to run the tool on all directories one after another.

my python script has code something like:

```
for directory in directories:
  os.popen('runtool_exec ' + directory)
```

But when I run the python script I get the following error messages repeatedly:

```
..
tail: write error: Broken pipe
date: write error: Broken pipe
..
```

All I do is login on a remote server using ssh where the tool, python script, and subject directories are kept. When I individually run the tool from command prompt using command like:

```
runtool_exec directory
```

it works fine. "broken pipe" error is coming only when I run using the python script.
Any idea, workaround?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The errors you see are because you're using `os.popen()` to run the command, which means a pipe is opened and connected to the command's `stdout`. Whenever the command (or anything it executes without redirecting `stdout`) wants to write to `stdout`, it'll try to write to the pipe. But you don't keep the pipe around, since you don't assign the result of `os.popen()` anywhere, so it's cleaned up by Python, and closed. So the processes that try to write to it encounter a broken pipe, and produce the error you see. (`os.popen()` does *not* redirect `stderr` to the pipe, so you still see the errors.)

Another problem in your `os.popen()` call is that you don't check to make sure `directory` doesn't contain any characters special to your shell. If the directory contained a quote, for example, or a *, weird things might happen. Using `os.popen()` like that is pretty bad.

You should use `subprocess.Popen()` instead, and explicitly tell it what you want to do with the process's output (both stdout and stderr.) You pass `subprocess.Popen()` a list of arguments (including the thing you want to start) instead of a single string, and it avoids the shell altogether -- no need to sanity-check your strings. If you really want to ignore the output, you would do it with something like:

```
devnull = open(os.devnull, 'w')
for directory in directories:
    subprocess.Popen(['runtool_exec', directory], stdout=devnull)
```

although I would strongly recommend at least doing some rudimentary checks on the result of subprocess.Popen to see if the process didn't execute prematurely or with an error code.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. This works. But how can I determine which process successfully completes and which got error?

Comment: and also how to determine which processes are still running? Is there any way to wait for the subprocesses to complete?

Comment: I am currently trying this:

log = open(logFile, 'a');
process = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout = log)
process.wait()
if process.returncode >=0:         print 'done !' 
else:
 print 'Error ! Process terminated badly'

But I see it does not wait for the processes to complete, and returncode is always 99.

please help.

Comment: If it didn't wait for the process to complete, then the returncode would be `None`, not 99. What you describe suggests *the command you start* doesn't wait for any processes *it* starts, and the command you start is what returns 99. The problem is with the process you start, not your use of `subprocess.Popen()`. (Also, if you always want to wait for the process to exit, using `subprocess.call()` is a little easier.)

Answer (score 0):

In case it's helpful for anyone else, this same problem can be a result of using pipes (|) in the shell command.  See here for solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/4106633/1904913