# Error when calling a file from python

Tags: python

I want to call an R program from a python script.

I wrote the following:

```
os.system("cat " + variableName + " | code.R")
```

It returns the error: sh: 1 : code.R: not found
cat: write error: Broken pipe

Yet, I am sure of the name of the R file.

Why is it not working?

Comment: I don´t know about *.R programs. But... is code.R a binary file or a script that has to be interpreted?

Comment: @RaydelMiranda A script that has to be interpreted

Comment: Is the `code.R` file in the same directory where from you are calling the python script?

Comment: What's in `variableName`?

Comment: @RaydelMiranda a text file that contains a matrix that will be processed by code.R

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106565/newbie-python-subprocess-problem-write-error-broken-pipe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if `code.R` is a script that has to be interpreted you must build the pipe to the interpreter not to the script. You receive a `Broken PIPE` error because `code.R` by it self don't know how to handle command line arguments.

On the other hand if what you want is store the `variable` value inside code.R you have to change `|` by `>>`.

os.system("cat " + variablename + ">> code.R")

**EDIT:** Since it's working from terminal, try this:

```
import subprocess
input = open(variableName, "r")
result = suprocess.call(["code.R"], stdin=input)    # result is the return code for the command being called.
```

see [subprocess.call](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) for more details.

Comment: Actually, code.R takes variable as input. What bothers me is that, from the terminal, cat variable | code.R worked perfectly. I would like to call this command from my python script, but for some reason it doesn't work...

Comment: the problem is then solved. Thank you guys for your help

Answer (score 1):

Is `code.R` in the current working directory? Is it executable? Can you run `cat xxx | code.R` from the shell and have it work properly, instead of running your python program?

Comment: Yes to all these questions (for the executable part, ls -lrt gives -rwxr-xr-x. I had executed the code.R from another directory before copying it to the one where my python script is located)

Comment: Do `print os.getcwd()` immediately before the `os.system()` call?