# Sorting error in bash?

Tags: html, bash, sorting, csv, pipe

I have this line of code where i go to the 4th column , get the maximum number and print it out

```
maximum=$(sort -u -k4 -nr Logname.csv | tail-2)
```

but its showing me this error

> sort: fflush failed: standard output: Broken pipe
>   sort: write error

Anyone can help me fix this?

Comment: Is it within a bash script or embedded in a Python or another language?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106565/newbie-python-subprocess-write-error-broken-pipe

Comment: Bug see here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/checksecurity/+bug/253619

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tail-2` is not a command, so there is no process running for `sort` to write its output to, hence the "broken pipe" error. You forgot the space:

```
maximum=$(sort -u -k4 -nr Logname.csv | tail -2)
                                           ^^^
```